# javascript: 10 x speedup via loop inline?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory

I'm running into a performance problem with a strange behaviour of javascript inside my
Firefox (13.0.1). The newest Chrome shows the same behaviour.

When I execute my javascript code which looks like the
code snippet below, the result is pretty slow.
However, I get about 10 x speedup if I simply inline the content of the
outer loop over 'j'. For my example application, this means that I'm
simply writing it two times for fixed values of 'j=0' and 'j=1' respectively, as 'm' equals 2. Of course, I don't want 'm'
to be hard-coded, so I'm asking myself what exactly causes this slowdown when
using a real loop?

Does anybody have an idea?

I'm running the code inside a web worker. Weird enough, the positive effect of the inlining does not occur if I execute the same in the main javascript context, instead of the worker's context. Nevertheless, executing the loop content only for one value of 'j' brings the huge speedup helps in all cases. Could this also have something to do with memory management?

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
//m: very small, 1-2
for (j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
  var attrib = attributes[j];

  //n: very large, ~3*10^6 elements
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

    var data = largeBuffer[i];

    //nc: very small, 2-3
    for (c = 0; c < nc; ++c) {
      var component;
      //compute 'component
      //..
      attrib.typedArray[baseIdx + c] |= component;
    }

    baseIdx += nc;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, the general practice of what you are doing is called "[loop unwinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding)".  (The linked Wikipedia page mentions speed advantages, but those are probably not sufficient to explain why you are seeing just a tremendous speedup; your case is likely related to JS-specific internals.)

Comment: Do you need to use Javascript to process circa 10+ million items on a client machine? Sounds like a lot of work for Javascript - can this process be restructured and the work done elsewhere? As a matter of interest, what is it doing?

Comment: It is decompressing data, so theoretically the process can be split into several 'chunks' (http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/13/speed-up-your-javascript-part-1/).
The size of the data in my current experiment is about 3 Million elements for n (see example code).

Comment: (... and each data element has several (2-3) components, so, in total, it has more than 10 million elements that are processed)

Comment: I see, and I can see where you're coming from doing it in Javascript. Is it JSON data? Will you really need all that data and will the user really look at it all? Can you just return part of the data instead and grab the rest if the user needs it?

Comment: Actually, it is all needed, so there's no chance to avoid the processing of a part of it.The data is read from and written to ArrayBuffer objects, I'm loading them directly via XmlHttpRequest.

Answer (score 4):

This is just an hypothesis. I do not know well the internals of JS interpreters.

Maybe when you inline the outer loop, the interpreter sees 4 times the same code and thus triggers the JIT. To the opposite, when you use a regular loop, the code is only seen once by the JIT.

Once again, this is only an hypothesis.

Comment: Yes, I thought of something like that... Maybe Js + Firefox + JIT is a good set of keywords for a search, so thanks a lot for the inspiration ;-)

The main problem from my point of view is the lack of understanding of what really happens there inside the JS component, which makes it pretty hard to write efficient code... I've already sent out a mail to Mozilla's dev-tech-js-engine list 4 days ago, but got no response, so any hints on help sources like that are still highly appreciated.

Comment: @Var In this blog post: http://blog.mrale.ph/post/24351748336/explaining-js-vm-in-js a guy tries to implement a JS interpreter in... JS. It is a good start to understand how it works.